# How to place a relative element after an absolute element and cause parent div to expand to fit children?

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm trying to understand css, so I tried my best to make my experimental code below as generic as possible.

I have a simple page, with two boxes, I wanted one of the boxes to be positioned a certain way which according to [Why does setting the `right` CSS attribute push an element to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082567/why-does-setting-the-right-css-attribute-push-an-element-to-the-left) requires me to set its position like so `position:absolute` However, I now want to add some divs which fall below my absolute div, furthermore I would like the parent div to expand to fit the size of the child divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #outer {
                position : relative;
                background-color : green;
                width : 500px;
                height : 500px;
/*                 overflow : hidden; */
/* I know from working with floating elements inside divs that this works
 *   to cause parent divs to exand out around floating children, but this
 *   does not do the same thing here, it lops off the bottom of the child divs
 *   if I un-comment the preceding line!
 */
            }

            #inner {
                position : absolute;
                background-color : blue;
                height : 400px;
                width : 400px;
                top : 10px;
                right : 20px;
            }


            #top_object {
                position : absolute;
                top : 450px;
            }

             .object {
                position : relative;
                width : 450px;
                height : 200px;
                background-color : yellow;
                margin-bottom : 25px;
            }
/*   The followsing was suggested by: 
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709442/make-divs-height-expand-with-its-content 
        But has no effect!
*/
           .clear {
                clear : both;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="inner">


            </div>
            <div id="top_object" class="object">
                Top Object
            </div>
            <div class="object">
                Second Object
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have my first div with class object and id top_object positioned at an absolute distance from the top like it appears. However, I would then like further object divs to flow below top object. In other words I want to use top_object to define an absolute position for the first instance of div with class object and then have the following divs with class object naturally flow down the page, with a 25px margin as set in `margin:25px;` of `.object`, following top_object without the need to set each object's `top:XXXpx;` attribute separately.

My first question is why does my second object appear above my first object, and how can I cause `relative` positioned objects to flow below an `absolute` positioned object?

Second how do I get background div to expand and around the children divs when floating divs are not used?

Furthermore, I am working to understand what is happening, although a direct answer to my question would be appreciated I would like to hear an explanation as to why what I am doing is wrong, and why any solution would fix it. I want to understand the logic behind css, not so much to see a specific code snippet which fixes the issue, although that would be nice too!

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, it is probably better asked over at [http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would challenge you to rethink your approach.  Absolute positioning is not necessary nearly as often as you might think.  For example, with `#top_object`, why don't you make it relative, with a margin-top of 450px?  And why do you need to make inner positioned absolutely? Why can't it be, for example, `float: right;`, but positioned relatively?

Comment: ok, i tried that but it moves everything down by 450px. and using float : right with relative positioning but pushes everything down by 450px.

Answer (score 5):

`position: absolute;` takes that object completely out of the document flow. So it's going to appear exactly where you tell it to be with your `top: 450px` and `right` or `left` selectors. That positioning won't effect any other element of your page (unless you cover up another object which will definitely happen without `z-index`) If you want everything to be placed below `#top_object` then you need to give it `display: block;` and whatever margin you need.

Also, `overflow: hidden` will cut off anything that is outside the defined width or height so you need to define min-width and min-height and then use overflow: auto instead of hidden.